# Shell script handle string with sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I have a text file, each line is one or more file paths separated with space, all the file has suffix **dl**, e.g.

```
/some/path/file.dl
/some/other/path/file2.dl /some/other/path2/file3.dl
/some/other/path3/file4.dl /some/other/path4/file5.dl ...
...
```

Now I need to transform the above file to another text file. Only the first file of every line should be changed to **/out/P{fileName}.h:**, **{fileName}** is the original file name without directory and suffix. e.g.

```
/out/Pfile.h:
/out/Pfile2.h: /some/other/path2/file3.dl
/out/Pfile4.h: /some/other/path2/file5.dl ...
...
```

So how can I write the linux shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
$ sed -r 's@^\S*/(\S*)\.dl@/out/P\1.h:@' input 
/out/Pfile.h:
/out/Pfile2.h: /some/other/path2/file3.dl
/out/Pfile4.h: /some/other/path4/file5.dl
```